# Cannot Mount AzureFileShare using Powershell on Windows Server

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, terraform

My objective is to attach a new Drive to Windows VM Mapping to Azure File Share
This needs to be done via Terraform

```
$UserName = $StorageAccount
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $StorageAccountKey -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $SecurePassword

# Mount the drive
    If (!(Test-Path O:)) {
        New-PSDrive -Name "O" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\$StorageAccount.file.core.windows.net\$FileShareName" -Persist -Scope "Global" -Credential $Credentials
    }
    else { Write-Host "The O: drive is already in use." }
```

The error I get is

*New-PSDrive : The specified network password is not correct*

Please help

Comment: The is pretty much self explanatory.

Comment: I checked the password and it is correct

Answer (score 0):

Not sure `-ArgumentList` would be a valid property of the object. Try this:
`$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($UserName, $SecurePassword)`

Comment: Using `-ArgumentList` is the same as enclosing in `(...)` and the same as `[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new(...)`

Comment: So the next question would be is where is `$StorageAccountKey` declared.